# Powershell DirectorySearcher Null Output

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directorysearcher

I'm writing a powershell script that searches for users inside an Active Directory OU and allows me to reset passwords by choosing matches from a list. I found a [Tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx) that uses the System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry and System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher, and modified it like so:

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP:\\[REDACTED]")

##ReadSTDIN
$strSearch = Read-Host -Prompt "Search"
$strCat = "(&(objectCategory=User)(Name=*" + $strSearch + "*))"
## Search Object
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strCat
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
#Load Required Properties into the dynObjLink
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName")
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SamAccountName")

##Magical Search Function
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll() 
$colResults.PropertiesLoaded

#for every returned userID add them to a table
ForEach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$a++
    $objResult.count
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties
        $objItem.name 
        $objItem.userPrincipalName
    $results.Add($a, $objItem.name + $objItem.userPrincipalName + $objItem.SamAccountName) 
}

#Print Table
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

This works well enough, but when it prints data I can only get the "first name" value of anything that comes back. Everything else becomes NULL and I can't figure out why.

```
Name Value                             
---- -----                                                
3    {James3 [REDACTED], $null, $null}      
2    {James2 [REDACTED], $null, $null}      
1    {James1 [REDACTED], $null, $null}
```

I've tried different kinds of authentication and manipulating values, but the DirectorySearcher object only seems to collect the "name" value of any record it returns, no matter what I load into it. Help?

Comment: try `$objResult.Properties['userPrincipalName']` instead of `$objResult.Properties.userPrincipalName`

Comment: Note that the `$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("x")` calls produce output. I would recommend `AddRange` instead: `$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("x","y",'z"))` - no output and you can add multiple properties with one line of code.

Comment: You also need `$result.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0]` instead of just `$result.Properties["userPrincipalName"]` because `$result.Properties["x"]` returns `ResultValuePropertyCollection`, not `String`, so you need to get its first element (`[0]`).

Comment: This was a long time ago, but I learned that for some reason previous versions of powershell called these objects in a way that made them case-sensitive. I made them all lowercase and managed to get the script to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit shorter (and PowerShell v2-compatible) way of doing this:

```
#requires -version 2
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $SearchPattern
)

$searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(&(objectClass=user)(name=$SearchPattern))"
$searcher.PageSize = 1000
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("name","samAccountName","userPrincipalName"))
$searchResults = $searcher.FindAll()
if ( $searchResults.Count -gt 0 ) {
  foreach ( $searchResult in $searchResults ) {
    $properties = $searchResult.Properties
    $searchResult | Select-Object `
      @{Name = "name";              Expression = {$properties["name"][0]}},
      @{Name = "sAMAccountName";    Expression = {$properties["samaccountname"][0]}},
      @{Name = "userPrincipalName"; Expression = {$properties["userprincipalname"][0]}}
  }
}
$searchResults.Dispose()
```

Note that there's no need to build a list and output afterwards. Just output each search result. Put this code in a script file and call it:

```
PS C:\Scripts> .\Searcher.ps1 "*dyer*"
```

If you omit the parameter, PowerShell will prompt you for it (because the parameter is marked as mandatory).

Answer (score 0):

try using Properties matching to the PropertiesToLoad

```
$entry = new-object -typename system.directoryservices.directoryentry  -ArgumentList $LDAPServer, "ldap", "esildap"
$entry.Path="LDAP://OU=childOU,OU=parentOU,DC=dc1,DC=dc2"
$searcher = new-object -typename system.directoryservices.directorysearcher -ArgumentList $entry

$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('samaccountname')
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('mail')
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('displayname')

$objs = $searcher.findall()

foreach($data in $objs)
{
    $samaccountname = $data.properties['samaccountname'][0] + ''
    $mail = $data.properties['mail'][0] + ''
    $displayname = $data.properties['displayname'][0] + ''
}

when accessing the properties of the resultset you get a System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection type for each property

 to get a string value for passing to a database the property value access the zero index of the object
```